# How do I store blob data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, spring-data-mongodb

I want to know if it's possible to insert blob data in mongodb. What is the procedure and is any other softwares required for this?

Answer (score 5):

There is no problem to store large files in the database. Use `mongofiles` See

[Article on mongodb.com](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/storing-large-objects-and-files-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely not. And before some fool just responds "[**GridFS**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/)", please **read** the documentation in the link.

Now that you have actually **read** the docs, consider that your **blob** (binary) data is probably under the 16MB BSON limitation. In which case, the answer is just Base64 encode it and put it into a field of your document.

Very Simple.

Comment: base64? Why? I mean, yes, disk is cheap, but that's just willful intent.

Comment: @mnemosyn Yes it is valid to just post in the binary data, or anything else supported in BSON. I guess I'm kind of on autopilot for the usual follow up of "wanting to embed image in web page" and images seems to be mostly what people are wanting to store

Comment: maybe something like "`GridFS` is mainly for distributing large files into chunks" would be good

Comment: I find this answer lacking, in the regard that the 16MB limitation is only an assumption. I am right now searching for this very topic, which landed me here, and I do in fact have data above that limit, potentially even several gigabytes in size (results of scientifical computations). If you have experience wth MongoDB, I'd implore you to make this case distinction. (Well, not sure if it is that useful to update a four year old answer, but again, I found it very quickly searching for mongodb and blobs, so has some significance.)

Comment: Base64 will of course bloat the object further and require CPU to store and retrieve,

Comment: I do not understand this answer (and this question is still the top Google search result for "mongodb binary blob"). To add another point: when deploying to GKE, permanent storage requires commissioning Filestore, which has similar $/GB to Atlas, but requires a 1 TB minimum commission.