# How to store pdf and images into database for notebook storing web app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, web

I want to make a note storing and viewing website but I don't know How to store images and pdf into the database and at the same time I want to upload pdf and images for storing.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can rename files upon upload and store them in a directory and
   save the file location as string in the database. Just make sure
   that every file has a unique name and you have used a filter for
   file upload. size limits and type filters and etc. And don't let any other user beside the owner of the file access it
2. or you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726821/how-to-insert-blob-data-in-mongodb-is-there-any-additaional-software-required). But saving files in database might reduce it's performance when using queries.

Comment: Then where should I store pdf and other documents??

Comment: Sounds, PDF and all other files in separate directories then just save the location of the file in database and when the user wants to access the file, generate a link for the file and send it to the user

Comment: Yeah but I want other users also can view that pdf and there will be lots of pdf data.

Comment: Yeah Thanks mate